# Convert seconds to days, hours

Tags: postgresql

I want convert seconds to days, hour, minutes seconds.

I use query like that.

```
select to_char(to_timestamp(2042658), 'dd "Days" HH24 "Hours" MI "Minutes" SS "Seconds"') as uptime
```

But that gives me 24 days, should be 23 and 18 hours should be 15.
What is right solution do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `TO_CHAR` with `justify_hours`

```
select to_char(justify_hours(interval '1 sec' * 2042658),
       'DD" days "HH24" hours "MI" minutes "SS" seconds"') as uptime
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=cd44162f68e79ff475ae32ef1f59d545)

Comment: It is working. Big thank you about that. But is there any easy solution to get a weeks, months, years? I tried W MM and YYYY with 66063756, but it is still counting only days.